# Stop a jquery expanding menu 'oscillating'

Tags: jquery, html, animation, drop-down-menu

I've built an expanding menu in jquery which works ok but when I roll in and out of the menu multiple times quickly the menu oscillates and and keeps animating open and closed after the mouse has rolled out of the menu which is verry annoying. Heres the code i have for opening the menu, its very simple.

```
$("#links").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#linksBody").slideDown(600, "easeOutExpo");
});

$("#links").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#linksBody" ).slideUp(600, "easeOutExpo");
});
```

and here's the site im having trouble with

http://www.pegbarandgrill.com/blog/

its the links & directory menu on the right. Does anyone know the best way of getting round this oscillation problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#links").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#linksBody").stop(1).slideDown(600, "easeOutExpo");
});

$("#links").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#linksBody" ).stop(1).slideUp(600, "easeOutExpo");
});
```

Another solution is to use a plugin like [hoverIntent](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFkQFjAA&url=http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html&ei=IMETUIHiN6qziQfKmYGIBw&usg=AFQjCNEID3O1NTtGoOWSwek7fDjVfcP1FQ)

Also, you can use `.hover()` and simplify things like this:

```
$("#links").hover(function(){
    $("#linksBody").stop(1).slideDown(600, "easeOutExpo");
},
  function(){
    $("#linksBody").stop(1).slideUp(600, "easeOutExpo");
});
```

I also wonder if the `easeOutExpo` could be causing you issues. Try without it and see if it helps?

Comment: This is slightly better but now I'm finding that the menu sonetimes gets stuck and wind complete the animation unless I reset it by reloading the page. This new code is live on the same link if you want to see, jt

Comment: I added your updated code and it still gets stuck, even if i try without the easeOutExpo, do you get the same behaviour on your end?

Comment: I added replaced the hover with hoverIntent and got rid of the stop() on the slideUp and it all seems to work now, Thanks!